# re render on state change with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

App won't re render different data on state change.

State does change in the dev tools but doesn't show on page.

Using button to filter.

```
export const StoriesPage = () => {
  const [storyIds, setStoryIds] = useState([]);
  const [storyUrl, setStoryUrl] = useState('top');

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = baseUrl;

    storyUrl === 'top'
      ? (url += 'topstories.json')
      : (url += 'newstories.json');

    getStoryIds(url).then(data => setStoryIds(data));
  }, [storyUrl]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setStoryUrl('new')}>New</button>
        <button onClick={() => setStoryUrl('top')}>Top</button>
      </div>
      {storyIds.map((storyId, index) => (
        <Story key={index} storyId={storyId} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the response from getStoryIds?

Comment: Your code looks okay.

Comment: I have check the state of storyIds and they do change. Weird. The state changes but no re render displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

Added a function that clears storyIds before setStoryUrl

```js
  const handleFilter = tag => {
    setStoryIds([]);
    setStoryUrl(tag);
  };
```